# How can I have the dependencies on an external project target be automatically rebuilt when the external project changes?

Tags: cmake, dependencies, cross-compiling

I'm working on a cross-compilation project with a top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file generating `Makefile`s. Some of the cross-compiled source code is generated by a host-based code generation tool; since that tool needs a different toolchain, the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` uses `ExternalProject_Add()` to invoke the code generator subdirectory's `CMakeLists.txt`, with `BUILD_ALWAYS` set to `TRUE`. The code generation targets depend on the code generator target, so during the initial build the code generator is built, and then the code is generated, and then the whole shebang is compiled into the final result.

If I change the source of the code generator then the code generator executable will be properly rebuilt on the next `make`. Problem: the dependent code generation targets will NOT be rebuilt. There seems to be no way with an `ExternalProject_Add()` target to indicate when/if any dependencies of the target should be rebuilt.

For instance, if the code generator target were configured using `Add_Custom_Command()`, then I'd use the `OUTPUT` keyword to specify the resulting executable file, and any dependent targets could be configured to automatically rebuild when the code generator executable's timestamp was updated.

(Edit for clarity: after specifying an `OUTPUT` file for `Add_Custom_Command()`, I'd then create a convenience target using `Add_Custom_Target()` whose `DEPENDS` keyword referenced the `Add_Custom_Command()`'s `OUTPUT` file. I'd then have the code generation targets depend on this convenience target. But, AFAIK, that won't work for me.)

Is there a way to configure an `ExternalProject_Add()`-based target so that dependent targets will be automatically rebuilt when the main target's output changes?

Comment: As far as I understand, only targets created with `add_executable` or `add_library` can have "main target's output" file. All other **targets** (including the one created by `ExternalProject_Add`) has no such file, so you need to **explicitly** depend from the code generator using DEPENDS parameter for `add_custom_command`. Note, that `add_custom_command` does NOT create/declare a **target**: this command just declares dependencies for a **file**. In CMake word a "file" and a "target" are different things.

Comment: Added clarification based on your final sentence. But, I don't think what first sentences are suggesting will work for me; somehow CMake has to trigger building a dependent target if a file (the `ExternalProject_Add()`'s output) is more recent than the dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to `IMPORT` a target based on the code generator executable. In my top-level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Run next-gen code generation
# Use ExternalProject_Add() because we are building this for the host
# We DO NOT want cross-compile toolchain applied here
set(CODEGEN_EXECUTABLE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/codegen/_build/codegen)
ExternalProject_Add(codegenExecutable
  SOURCE_DIR        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/codegen
  # The two "--unset" options tell it to use the host defaults rather than the configured ones.
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env --unset=CC --unset=CXX ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -H. -B_build
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  BUILD_IN_SOURCE   TRUE
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL  TRUE
  BUILD_ALWAYS      TRUE
)

# Imported target, so that any change in the code generator will result in rerunning the
# code generation.
add_executable(codegen IMPORTED)
set_property(
    TARGET codegen
    PROPERTY
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CODEGEN_EXECUTABLE}"
)
add_dependencies(codegen codegenExecutable)
```

Any of the code generation targets are set to depend on codegen. The first time I build:

1. The `codegenExecutable` external project is built, creating the `${CODEGEN_EXECUTABLE}` executable
2. The `codegen` target's timestamp is set by the executable's timestamp
3. All of the code generation tasks that depend on `codegen` are rebuilt

With no changes, subsequent builds do the following:

1. The `codegenExecutable` external project is built, but since none of its source has changed the executable isn't rebuilt and doesn't change its timestamp
2. The `codegen` target's timestamp doesn't change
3. The code generation tasks that depend on `codegen` aren't rebuilt

If I touch any `codegen` source and build, then:

1. The `codegenExecutable` external project is built, creating a new  `${CODEGEN_EXECUTABLE}` executable with an updated timestamp
2. The `codegen` target's timestamp is updated by the executable's timestamp
3. The code generation tasks that depend on `codegen` **are** rebuilt

I believe that if I set up an `EXPORT`ed target from the `codegen`'s `CMakeLists.txt` then I wouldn't have to hard-code the executable path. A task for the future...

Comment: Shouldn't the line `add_dependencies(codegen codegen2Executable)` be `add_dependencies(codegen codegenExecutable)`?

Comment: Right: it should. Will edit to fix. (Thanks.)